# PDO::__construct (sqlite) try/catch use

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Trying to use a try/catch block for a connection to a sqlite database I found that when a database connection couldn't be made, the database file was created. Checking [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) the following issue is reported :

> If 'example.db' does not exist, no exception is thrown but the file 'example.db' is created.

Is there a solution to this 'problem' - I hesitate to call it that because presumably this is by design.

What I need is for the error to be caught as opposed to the database created.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this would be to check if the file exists, otherwise throw an Exception :

```
if (!file_exists( 'example.db')) {
    throw new Exception('No database file');
}
```